# PHP syntax error echoing out HTML table with PHP in it

Tags: php, html

There is the code i wanted to use to echo out HTML table with som PHP in it.
EDIT: Im sorry I think the problem is that I didnt show you the whole code. Maybe this changes something.

```
<!doctype html> 
<html> 
  <head>
     <title>Search</title>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">  
  </head>
  <body>

<?php
include("config.php");
if (isset($_POST['input'])){

    $input = $_POST['input'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE location LIKE '{$input}%' 
  OR FileName LIKE '{$input}%' OR ImageSize LIKE '{$input}%' OR MediaDuration LIKE '{$input}%' 
  OR VideoFrameRate LIKE '{$input}%' OR CreateDate LIKE '{$input}%' OR author LIKE '{$input}%' OR tags LIKE '{$input}%' OR genre LIKE '{$input}%' OR rating LIKE '{$input}%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

    $fetchVideos = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM videos WHERE location LIKE '{$input}%' OR FileName LIKE '{$input}%' OR ImageSize LIKE '{$input}%' OR MediaDuration LIKE '{$input}%' 
  OR VideoFrameRate LIKE '{$input}%' OR CreateDate LIKE '{$input}%' OR author LIKE '{$input}%' OR tags LIKE '{$input}%' OR genre LIKE '{$input}%' OR rating LIKE '{$input}%'");
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetchVideos)){
       
       
      echo '<?php
      $select="select * from videos";
      $result=mysqli_query($con,$select);
  ?>
  <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-top: 50px;">
      <tr>
          <th> Video </th>
          <th> Názov </th>
          <th> Autor </th>
          <th> Tagy </th>
          <th> Žáner </th>
          <th> Hodnotenie </th>
          <th> Rozlíšenie videa </th>
          <th> Počet Snímkov </th>
          <th> Dĺžka videa</th>s
          <th> Dátum Vytvorenia </th>
      </tr>
      <?php foreach($result as $rows) { ?>
          <tr>
              <td><video src="<?php echo $location; ?>" controls width='320px' height='320px' ></video></td>
              <td><?php echo $rows['FileName']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $rows['author']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $rows['tags']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $rows['genre']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $rows['rating']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $rows['ImageSize']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $rows['VideoFrameRate']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $rows['MediaDuration']; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $rows['CreateDate']; ?></td>
          </tr>
      <?php } ?>
  </table>';


       </body>
</html>
```

I have trouble with the part where im trying to use PHP in the echo function. I dont know where the problem is.

```
<tr>
             <td><video src='".$location."' controls width='320px' height='320px' ></video></td>  
             <td><?php echo $rows['FileName']; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $rows['author']; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $rows['tags']; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $rows['genre']; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $rows['rating']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $rows['ImageSize']; ?></td> 
           <td><?php echo $rows['VideoFrameRate']; ?></td> 
             <td><?php echo $rows['MediaDuration']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $rows['CreateDate']; ?></td> 
           </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?php
    $select="select * from videos";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$select);
?>
<table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-top: 50px;">
    <tr>
        <th> Video </th>
        <th> Názov </th>
        <th> Autor </th>
        <th> Tagy </th>
        <th> Žáner </th>
        <th> Hodnotenie </th>
        <th> Rozlíšenie videa </th>
        <th> Počet Snímkov </th>
        <th> Dĺžka videa</th>
        <th> Dátum Vytvorenia </th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($result as $rows) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><video src="<?php echo $location; ?>" controls width='320px' height='320px' ></video></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['FileName']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['author']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['tags']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['genre']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['rating']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['ImageSize']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['VideoFrameRate']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['MediaDuration']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $rows['CreateDate']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

But I'd suggest you learn how to mix html with php.
First try to only output the data with php (everything inside a single `<?php … ?>`) and not using any html.
Then in the next step you could try mixing in the html. Go slow and step by step. This way you will notice, when you made a syntax error.

Edit:

Try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
     <title>Search</title>
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KK94CHFLLe+nY2dmCWGMq91rCGa5gtU4mk92HdvYe+M/SXH301p5ILy+dN9+nJOZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>

<?php
include("config.php");
if (isset($_POST['input'])) {

    $input = $_POST['input'];
        $select="SELECT * from VIDEOS";
        $result=mysqli_query($con,$select);

?>
        <table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-top: 50px;">
                <tr>
                        <th> Video </th>
                        <th> Názov </th>
                        <th> Autor </th>
                        <th> Tagy </th>
                        <th> Žáner </th>
                        <th> Hodnotenie </th>
                        <th> Rozlíšenie videa </th>
                        <th> Počet Snímkov </th>
                        <th> Dĺžka videa</th>s
                        <th> Dátum Vytvorenia </th>
                </tr>
                <?php while($row = $result->mysqli_fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                <tr>
                        <td><video src="<?php echo $location; ?>" controls width="320px" height="320px" ></video></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['FileName']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['author']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['tags']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['genre']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['rating']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['ImageSize']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['VideoFrameRate']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['MediaDuration']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $row['CreateDate']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } // end of while loop ?>
        </table>';

    <?php } // end of if-clause ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

You should also use prepared statements in your SQL-Queries, otherwise your program is vulnerable to sql injections.

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding. I edited your post with image of syntax method.

Comment: @Petco Don't surround the code I posted with an echo '…'; . Also read [this](https://techgoeasy.com/how-to-use-php-scripts-with/)

Comment: Still doesnt work :/ I updated the syntax error image above.

Comment: You still have everything surrounded with an echo statement.
Remove `echo '` in the first line and remove `':` in the last line.

Comment: @Petco Also, you should update your original question, with the changes you are making, so everyone can see them. Otherwise this question will get removed.

Comment: Hello I posted my whole code I think thats where the problem is.

Comment: @Petco See the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your are echoing `$` as comment and not a variable. You should use the *backtick* (`).

`` echo `$ >your codes here< $`; ``

```html
echo `<table class="table table-bordered" style="margin-top: 50px;"> 
   <tr> 
   <?php 
   $select="select * from videos"; 
   $result=mysqli_query($con,$select); 
   ?>
   <!--<th colspan="4"><h2>Student Record</h2></th> -->
   </tr> 
         <th> Video </th>
      <th> Názov </th>
         <th> Autor </th>
         <th> Tagy </th>
         <th> Žáner </th>
         <th> Hodnotenie </th>
      <th> Rozlíšenie videa </th> 
      <th> Počet Snímkov </th> 
         <th> Dĺžka videa</th>
      <th> Dátum Vytvorenia </th> 
   </tr> 
   <tr>
   <td><video src='".$location."' controls width='320px' height='320px' ></video></td>  
   <td><?php echo $rows['FileName']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $rows['author']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $rows['tags']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $rows['genre']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $rows['rating']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $rows['ImageSize']; ?></td> 
   <td><?php echo $rows['VideoFrameRate']; ?></td> 
   <td><?php echo $rows['MediaDuration']; ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $rows['CreateDate']; ?></td> 
   </tr> 
   <?php 
         } 
   ?> 
</table> `;
```

Comment: Hello @Newbee. Thank you for reply. I added  a picture of your code giving me syntax error.